# Why isn't my flash[:alert] working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, alert

after my user uploads a file and hits "submit" i would like to alert them that the upload was successful. But nothing happens when I do.

Here is in the controller:

```
def create
    # make a new picture with what picture_params returns (which is a method we're calling)
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      # if the save for the picture was successful, go to index.html.erb
      redirect_to pictures_url
      flash[:alert] = "Upload successful!"
    else
      # otherwise render the view associated with the action :new (i.e. new.html.erb)
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Form:

```
<container>
<center>
<%= form_for @picture do |f| %>
  <input type="file" multiple>  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  <p>Drag your files here or click in this area.</p>
  <button type="submit"> <%= f.submit "Save" %> Upload </button>
  <% if flash[:alert] %>
    <div class="alert"><%= flash[:alert] %></div>
  <% end %>
</form>
<% end %>
</container>
```

Thanks!

Comment: because you redirect (equivalent of a `return`) before setting your `flash[:alert]`

Comment: i switched them around and it still doesn't work?

Comment: I don't think `redirect_to` will return and stop executing rest of the lines after it.  Do you have `flash[:alert]` in your picture's `index.html.erb`.  The form you're trying to display `flash[:alert]` in is not rendered when picture saves successfully.  You should check your index file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your create method should be like this:

```
def create
    @picture = Picture.new(picture_params)
    if @picture.save
      flash[:alert] = "Upload successful!"
      redirect_to pictures_url
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

The redirect should be after the flash. You can also do it like this:

```
redirect_to pictures_url, alert: "Upload successful!"
```

And the `div` you are creating for flash message should be on the index page of pictures i.e., the page you are redirecting to and not in the form itself.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! it shows up just as text on the page though. I want a popup box thing though...any idea? thanks again kind one~

Comment: Do you need a alert box or just a box around it?